# Resources in MSProject AddIn: Add a server related resource to the local version of the project

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-server-2010, psi

Currently I am developing an AddIn for MS Project 2010.

In this AddIn the user filters all employees stored as MS Project Resources on the Project Server by several criteria. After finding a matching human resource the user should be able to add this resource to a selected task.

Unfortunately I do not find the link between adding the resource locally by

```
 _activeProject.Resources.Add("ResourceName")
```

and the resource being stored on the server. "ResourceName" shown in Project has no connection to "ResourceName" on the server.

I tried to load the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Resource` somehow from the server via the PSI and add it to the project team by:

```
    Dim projectTeamRow As SvcProject.ProjectTeamDataSet.ProjectTeamRow = projectTeamDs.ProjectTeam.NewProjectTeamRow()
    projectTeamRow.PROJ_UID = projectGuid
    projectTeamRow.RES_UID = resGuid
    projectTeamRow.NEW_RES_UID = resGuid
    projectTeamDs.ProjectTeam.AddProjectTeamRow(projectTeamRow)
```

But that's not really what I want. I simply need to add a server related resource to the local version of the project. In other words: I am looking for a way to convert a `SvcProject.ProjectTeamDataSet.ProjectTeamRow` to a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Resource`.

I really hope somebody can help me, since all my researches failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add resource from Project server to your project you need to know ID of the resource (Not GUID). This information is stored in the **RES_ID** column. Just quest resource from server and get the ID.

If you plan to add several resources - I would recommend to cache a list of resources locally. I'm using this query to organize several dictionaries inside of my add-on:

```
ResourceDataSet resourceDs = new ResourceDataSet();

PSLibrary.Filter resourceFilter = new Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Library.Filter();
resourceFilter.FilterTableName = resourceDs.Resources.TableName;

resourceFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(resourceDs.Resources.TableName, resourceDs.Resources.RES_IDColumn.ColumnName, PSLibrary.Filter.SortOrderTypeEnum.None));
resourceFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(resourceDs.Resources.TableName, resourceDs.Resources.RES_UIDColumn.ColumnName, PSLibrary.Filter.SortOrderTypeEnum.None));
resourceFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(resourceDs.Resources.TableName, resourceDs.Resources.RES_NAMEColumn.ColumnName, PSLibrary.Filter.SortOrderTypeEnum.None));
resourceFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(resourceDs.Resources.TableName, resourceDs.Resources.RES_TYPEColumn.ColumnName, PSLibrary.Filter.SortOrderTypeEnum.None));
resourceFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(resourceDs.Resources.TableName, resourceDs.Resources.RES_INITIALSColumn.ColumnName, PSLibrary.Filter.SortOrderTypeEnum.None));
resourceFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(resourceDs.Resources.TableName, resourceDs.Resources.RES_EXTERNAL_IDColumn.ColumnName, PSLibrary.Filter.SortOrderTypeEnum.None));
resourceFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(resourceDs.Resources.TableName, resourceDs.Resources.RES_IS_WINDOWS_USERColumn.ColumnName, PSLibrary.Filter.SortOrderTypeEnum.None));
resourceFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(resourceDs.Resources.TableName, resourceDs.Resources.WRES_ACCOUNTColumn.ColumnName, PSLibrary.Filter.SortOrderTypeEnum.None));
resourceFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(resourceDs.Resources.TableName, resourceDs.Resources.WRES_EMAILColumn.ColumnName, PSLibrary.Filter.SortOrderTypeEnum.None));
resourceFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(resourceDs.Resources.TableName, resourceDs.Resources.RES_TIMESHEET_MGR_UIDColumn.ColumnName, PSLibrary.Filter.SortOrderTypeEnum.None));

resourceDs = ReadResources(resourceFilter.GetXml(), false);
```

The query is defined as extension of **ResourceClient** class from PSI.

As soon as you know ID of the resource just execute: `Application.EnterpriseResourceGet(resId, omissing);`

Application is from `Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject`.

This command will load the resource from Project Server into Active Project. Oh yes, please don't forget to check that your project is active when you call the command.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Can you tell me where to find documentation for things like this. Why is it so hard to find...